# jQuery error submit form validation

Tags: jquery, forms

I need to validate input using JavaScript and jQuery when someone submit my newsletter form

for some reason it does not work. it submit the form without alerting any errors

Here's what i have so far:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
  function go() {
      if($('#name').val() == '') {
          alert('error: name is required');
      }
      $('form').submit();
  }
  });


  </script>
  </head>

  <form method="post" action="">
    Name *<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
    E-Mail *<input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>

    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="go();">
  </form>
```

Why I don't see the alert when I don't put anything in the name and then submit the form?

Comment: i recommend to use: [jQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Rather than using `onclick` on the submit button, use `onsubmit="return go();` on the form element. Or, use jQuery `$('form').submit(function(){ ... });`

And, once you encounter an error, you need to `return false` from the function to prevent it from executing any further.

Comment: While technically correct, I strongly advise against using client-side validation and especially against using `alert()` boxes to show errors.

Comment: can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @liho1eye why would you advise against it? It's just one part. Server side validation is necessary, but client side validation helps to prevent the form being posted to the server for processing if it is incomplete. Which saves time and http requests.

Comment: Unless OP is writing a new Facebook or google.com, HTTP requests are **really** cheap to come by. Time spent writing (and maintaining in sync) server and client side validation usually isn't. Even if your form is a part of a larger page, which you don't want to reload on submit, it is still much cheaper to simply do AJAX post and reload the widget with the form inside it (with validation rendered server side). Alerts on their own is pretty bad UX. It gets progressively worse if there are several validation errors on the form.

Comment: Additionally I've seen developers trick them selves more than once into trusting client-side validation, even though when confronted about it, they know not to do it. Duplication of logic is always bad.

Comment: @liho1eye I agree with your points. Even I choose server side only checks if I'm short on development time, however, it is not a reason to advise against client side checks. While alert is not the best UI to report errors, one has to start from somewhere and improve upon.